# Writing parquet files to S3 using AWS java lambda

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, protocol-buffers, parquet

I'm writing AWS lambda that reads protobuf obejcts from Kinesis and would like to write them to s3 as parquet file.

I saw there's a implementation of ParquetWriter for protobuf called ProtoParquetWriter, which is good. My problem is that ProtoParquetWriter expects a Path in its constructor.

What's the right way to do that without saving the content as parquet file, assuming I'm not using the file system at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a List (can be any complex object), sample code to read/write protobuf S3 parquet

```
    public class SimpleS3ParquetUtilities implements S3Utilities {

    final Logger logger;
    String PATH_SCHEMA = "s3a";
    CompressionCodecName compressionCodecName;

    public SimpleS3ParquetUtilities(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.compressionCodecName = CompressionCodecName.UNCOMPRESSED;
    }

    public SimpleS3ParquetUtilities(Logger logger, CompressionCodecName compressionCodecName) {
        this.logger = logger;
        this.compressionCodecName = compressionCodecName;
    }

    @Override
    public String writeTransactions(String bucket, String objectKey, List<Transaction> transactions)
            throws Exception {
        if (objectKey.charAt(0) != '/')
            objectKey = "/" + objectKey;
        Path file = new Path(PATH_SCHEMA, bucket, objectKey);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        // convert the list into protobuf 
        List<TransactionProtos.Transaction> protoTransactions = Convertor.toProtoBuf(transactions);
        try (ProtoParquetWriter<TransactionProtos.Transaction> writer = new ProtoParquetWriter<TransactionProtos.Transaction>(
                file, TransactionProtos.Transaction.class, this.compressionCodecName,
                ProtoParquetWriter.DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE, ProtoParquetWriter.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE)) {

            for (TransactionProtos.Transaction transaction : protoTransactions) {
                writer.write(transaction);
            }
        }
        logger.info("Parquet write elapse:[{}{}] Time:{}ms items:{}", bucket, objectKey,
                sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), transactions.size());
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public List<Transaction> readTransactions(String bucket, String pathWithFileName)
            throws Exception {
        if (pathWithFileName.charAt(0) != '/')
            pathWithFileName = "/" + pathWithFileName;
        Path file = new Path(PATH_SCHEMA, bucket, pathWithFileName);
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        try (ParquetReader<TransactionProtos.Transaction.Builder> reader = ProtoParquetReader.<TransactionProtos.Transaction.Builder>builder(
                file).build()) {
            List<TransactionProtos.Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<TransactionProtos.Transaction>();
            TransactionProtos.Transaction.Builder builder = reader.read();
            while (builder != null) {
                TransactionProtos.Transaction transaction = builder.build();
                transactions.add(transaction);
                builder = reader.read();
            }
            logger.info("Parquet read elapsed:[{}{}] Time:{}ms items:{}", bucket, pathWithFileName,
                    sw.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS), transactions.size());
            return Convertor.fromProtoBuf(transactions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a few details?  What jars are you using?  How about some imports?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write to S3, you can set the Path as `Path("s3a://<bucketName>/<s3Key>")`. And don't forget to set S3 credentials in the configurations:

```
    conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", "<s3AccessKey");
    conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", "<s3SecretKey");
```